# Issues Creating Bootable USB

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

I'm trying to get Ubuntu 12.10 Desktop onto a flash drive (formatted to FAT), to repair a Windows laptop I have.  Per the Ubuntu site:

- I've installed the Pendrive Universal USB Installer.
- I had it download the ISO file ***ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso***.

But when it completes and I try to boot it up on the laptop, I'm getting the error:

```
No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!
```

I've read the info about renaming the **isolinux** files to **syslinux** but, that has not been helpful.  The **syslinux** folder already exists.  However, it appears that it's not being extracted correctly.  All the file names (within the syslinux folder) seem to be random bits of words. **See below:**

[image]

If I use 7-zip to manually extract the ISO file, the **isolinux** folder is there but, not the **syslinux** folder.  The correct files appear to be in this folder.  I tried creating the flash drive with UNetBootin, using the same ISO file and when I went to boot the laptop, all I got was a generic "boot error".

What am I missing here?

This is my first go-around with Ubuntu so, any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Try [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) or [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) to create your USB.

Comment: @Mitch - As I mentioned, I've tried UNetBootin.  Will test out YUMI later.

Comment: Is your USB drive formatted as FAT32? If not try it.

Comment: @Misery Everything I've read suggests that flash drives formatted as FAT32 will not work.  Is that not correct?  I don't even think thats the cause of the issue.  The syslinux folder is just getting messed up while being unpacked.

Comment: I have just created one with Unetbootin on a FAT32 flash drive and it works pretty well. You can use `cfdisk` to easily remove the existing partition from the drive, and create a new one with the type `0B` (FAT32). Just be sure, that you are handling the correct device.

Comment: @grimpitch I'll have to test that. Out of curiosity, what ISO did you use?

Comment: The standard ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso from ubuntu.com

Comment: @grimpitch Well, I tried it last night and no luck. Still getting a generic 'boot error'. Could possibly be a problem with the BIOS. I saw some forum posts stating that the 'USB mass storage emulation type' needed to be updated but, this option was not in my BIOS.

Comment: It can be a BIOS bug or missing feature, perhaps you can look for a BIOS update if you haven't already yet. Anyways you can try the Startup Disk Creator utility, that is installed by default, or the `dd` command to copy the iso image to the flash drive: `dd if=PATH_TO_ISO of=/dev/sdX bs=4096` where sdX is the flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple in Ubuntu.  If you can burn the iso to a CD/DVD then you will be able to install that way immediately.  Or you have the option to "Try Ubuntu without installing" from the CD/DVD and easily create a Ubuntu Live bootable USB flash drive to install from.

To install the CD/DVD you can follow these instructions: 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest

To install the USB drive: 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu 
or something a little fancier: 
[Live USB on a 2-partition usb-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423300/live-usb-on-a-2-partition-usb-drive/423402#423402)

As for your issues installing, the [tutorial](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) is very clear.  I would recommend clearing the USB flash drive by deleting all files from or reformatting first, to give it a fresh do-over.  To better assist with that particular problem, a more descriptive description would help.  For instance: how did you boot up to the laptop before the error was displayed?