# Is it possible to install a task in a different drive?

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, tasksel

I have a very limited hard disk space

Is it possible to install `lubuntu` using `tasksel` on a USB disk for example?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. "tasksel" will use the pre-defined locations for files for installing. Any installation method in Ubuntu for installing a complete desktop will be into the default location unless you want to install it compiling it all yourself.

The are some easier alternatives.

If you have 2 USB sticks you could download the ISO to 1 stick and install it onto the other one using the "startup disk creator".

Or create 2 partitions on the USB stick (1 just large enough to store the ISO) and then install onto the 2nd partition (see [Live USB on a 2-partition usb-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423300/live-usb-on-a-2-partition-usb-drive) )

Comment: Thank you, the thing is booting from USB will significantly slow down the performance; there's a 4GB SSD built in. Is there a way to change these "default locations"?

Comment: @HosamHittini Don't thank posters!  ;-) If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby I'm still expecting a reply.

Comment: @HosamHittini: Your original question has been answered.   If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: @Fabby If the "default locations" can be changed, the answer would be different

Comment: @HosamHittini only when installing from source you can alter the destination (is already in the answer). So no. Best bet is still to do the installation over USB stick. Slow yes, but it will work

Comment: @HosamHittini: read the [File Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml) and then you'll know why "non-default locations" are a bad idea...  Use symlinks instead.