# create bootable usb with partitioned usb

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, usb

I have sandisk 32 GB USB partitioned in two partitions. Both are FAT32 format and first is 20 GB and second partition is of 10 GB.

I use 1st partition for file storage as it is detected in windows and 2nd partition is not detected (don't event want to) which I want to create bootable persistent Ubuntu.

While using **Startup disk creator** in Ubuntu 16.04, it only shows whole USB as a single and there is no option to select from two partitions.
[image: Startup Disk Creator]

How could I use 2nd partition to create bootable using **Startup Disk Creator**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Live USB on a 2-partition usb-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423300/live-usb-on-a-2-partition-usb-drive)

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool that can create a persistent live drive and make partitions automatically, [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). The first partition 'usbdata' has an NTFS file system, and the intention is to use it for file sharing with Windows computers.

The following links helps you install and use mkusb for this purpose,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I believe your answer is right here:

[Live USB on a 2-partition usb-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423300/live-usb-on-a-2-partition-usb-drive)

**ENDUPDATE**

OK, so I created two partitions on an 8gb flash drive, I then put an ISO on the drive using Disk Image Writer  Unfortuently it over wrote all the partitions and created this:

[image: After ISO burned]

As you can see the ISO takes up very little space including the second partition which I believe is the swap.  But it did leave 6.6gb of free space.

My suggestion is that you save the data off your drive, burn the ISO, and then take the free space and make that data space, and move your data back on there.  As long as you use FAT or NTFS, windows should not have an issue mounting the drive.

Comment: This will not show 2nd partition in windows system. Windows will only show 1st partition which is the bootable USB partition

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this as well. There is a problem though. In windows only the first partition will be visible. Even if you use startup disk creator in Linux, your windows will only see the partition containing the bootable Linux.

However this should only be true on USB pen drives. USB HDD or SSD should not encounter this problem.

Comment: Let me test, and I will respond hopefully with an answer.

Comment: @tinus087 just FTR (and the search engines): up on from 2017 Windows 10 is able to mount several (even several primary) partitions from one USB stick

Answer (score -1):

Making the drive be bootable requires overwriting the beginning of the whole drive so all partitions are lost because the partition table is overwritten.  Once you have made a Linux boot image then adding a FAT or NTFS partition after that should be seen be Windows.  *Backup your data*.

Comment: Your answer does not seem to deal with OPs question here. Please be specific to OPs question when posting.