# Booting from ISO image located on a filesystem that's on a USB stick

Tags: boot, usb, encryption

I have an ISO image of a Ubuntu based system (Linux Mint 19).

I'd like to put it on an USB stick and be able to boot from it, but I'd like to keep the rest of the USB stick writable (and encrypted; if the ISO image may be on the encrypted partition too, all the better).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Live USB on a 2-partition usb-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423300/live-usb-on-a-2-partition-usb-drive)

Comment: @hiigaran: there is no mention of encryption on the page you reference. The OP asks for encryption.

Comment: Why encrypt the image, it is not unique.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron That's a good point. (Also thought of it later). The image doesn't need to be encrypted.

Comment: Plus the main answer on https://askubuntu.com/questions/423300/live-usb-on-a-2-partition-usb-drive is obsolete. Startup disk creator stopped supporting persistence with 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a Ubuntu computer, **mkusb** is likely the most suitable USB creation tool for you.

It builds a bootable flash drive with a FAT32 boot partition, thus booting BIOS or UEFI.

There is a ISO9660 read only secure OS partition. There is no need to encrypt this partition as it is standard unmodified OS.

The casper-rw Persistence partition offers persistence only limited by flash drive size.

A NTFS usbdata partition is usable for data on Linux or Windows computers.

Mkusb offers options to backup and restore the home directory, Wipe and restore the USB, write bootable images to USB, and has a Windows installer.

The home directory may be encrypted using standard encryption software.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

If you are restricted to Windows, YUMI makes a good persistent flash drive, however I have not tried encryption with a YUMI drive. It's casper-rw file is different than most.