# Is it possible to save an image of my current kubuntu installation?

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, live-usb

Is it possible for my current kubuntu 20.04 installation to be saved preferably in a bootable USB? I have several productivity apps and of course files and documents and would like to avoid installation from scratch and putting file backups in place when moving to a new machine.

Comment: You can use Clonezilla according to [this link to a similar question at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958242/fastest-way-to-copy-hdd/958248#958248)

Comment: My preference is Gnome-Disks. Boot from Live USB, open Disks, select Drive Options icon, upper right, select Create Disk Image. You can restore the disk image using Rufus, Etcher, Gnome-Disks, dd or my preference mkusb. Clonezilla is too complicated for me. The image will be bootable when restored to USB or you can flash directly to your new Drive.

Answer (score 1):

i prefer using dd as it clones the disc comppletey.
to do so you can use a bootable ubuntu USB device which is either big enough to store your image or use an external hdd drive.

you can refer here [Live USB on a 2-partition usb-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423300/live-usb-on-a-2-partition-usb-drive) to setup a 2 partion usb drive.

then boot from the usb and simply clone your disc (i assume its /dev/sda/, but can be /dev/mmcblk or similar) by using

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/ubuntu/<usb part2>/sda.img bs=32M
```

to restore your complete disc then boot up again and use

```
dd if=/media/ubuntu/<usb part2>/sda.img of=/dev/sda bs=32M
```

its important to clone the complete drive - e.g. using /dev/sda1 would only clone the first partition